# How to export very large merged dataframe?

Tags: python, export-to-csv, dask-dataframe

I have two dataframes that I need to merge. `df1` has over 50 columns and `df2` has over 20 columns. I used the following code to merge:

```
#Using pandas would crash the IDE, so I used dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
```

```
out = dd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer')
```

These lines above work great, it merges and I can even check `dtypes` and `list(columns)`. However, when I try to use `out.to_csv()` or even `out.head()` my runtime crashes because I used too much RAM.

Does anyone know of a turnaround to at least exporting the dataframe as a CSV without crashing my runtime? I have tried different IDEs and I encounter the same issue.

Comment: In `to_csv`, you have an option to save a zipped csv. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html  Can you try that?

Comment: Try `to_hdf` for large dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase the number of partitions to prevent memory errors.  Read more about the dask dataframe design [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html#design).

```
out = dd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', npartitions=output_parts)
```